# Unable to get related Table Records as Lists in F# Dapper

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to use the F# Dapper wrapper at https://github.com/Dzoukr/Dapper.FSharp

It says , on the page:

**Dapper.FSharp will map each joined table into separate record and return it as list of 'a * 'b tuples**

But it doesn't. For the following code, I get a record for each order and each row of the order detail table ( i.e. no "Master detail").  am I doing something wrong or am I not understanding this correctly.  I am really struggling with ANY of the F# data access libraries to find one that works well in F#

```
let orders = 
    select {
        table "Orders"
        leftJoin "OrderDetails" "OrderId" "Orders.Id"
        where ( eq "Orders.ReviewSent" false +
                gt "Orders.OrderDate" startDate +
                lt "Orders.OrderDate" endDate
        )
    }
    |> conn.SelectAsync<Order, OrderDetail>
```

Comment: Have you tried SqlCommandProvider? It works great with SQL Server in my experience.

Comment: @brianberns  I've spent hours trying to get things to work with F# . SqlCommandprovider seems good for selects - but once I map to the type records - it seems I would have to map every single property back for updates in tedious code functions & parameters for each property.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like there's another Dapper library for F# called [FSharp.Data.Dapper](https://github.com/AlexTroshkin/fsharp-dapper). Might be worth a look if you're willing. I'll also see if I can figure out this Dapper.FSharp thing.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing. I successfully created a left join using the Northwind database, and get a sequence of `(Order, OrderDetail)` tuples, as advertised. Can we see more of your code? Keep in mind that your `orders` value is a `Task`, as you have it written now. You still need to execute that task.

Comment: @brianberns  I do get a sequence of Order , Orderdetails - I guess I was expecting to get a sequence tuples of Order, List<Orderdetails> for the one to many representation of that.

Comment: A join flattens out that relationship, by definition. If you want master-detail, "you can perform multiple queries - one to get the parent data, and another to obtain related data". (That's a quote from [Managing Relationships With Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/relationships).)

Comment: @brianberns  Thanks you.  So SQLCommandProvider has no direct Mapping back from objects?  It's all manual / parameters?

Comment: Right, there's no built-in mapping between object and relation in SqlCommandProvider. However, it looks like you could use old-fashioned [DataTables](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/data%20modification.html) to avoid the manual mapping. (I haven't tried that.)

Comment: @brianberns  Thanks - as much as I like F# .. I think I am going to go back to C# & do some functional styles there.  I have spent too many days on this.

Comment: Generally I think it's easier to discover potential problems with plain Dapper and Dapper.Contrib. If you figure out problems in queries there, you might then be able to rewrite the resulting source into something workable for these F# specific libraries.